# using a constructor in a method

Tags: java, binary

I have been working on an assignment, and I'm fairly new to programming, and I'm struggling to use the first constructor I made in the add method. I have tested both constructors to make sure they work, I just don't know how to call it to use it in the method. The first constructor is meant to take a number and convert it into an array of booleans, true being a 1 and false being 0. The booleans are meant to represent binary numbers. The second constructor is meant to take a string and convert it into a BinaryNumber, as I created in the first constructor. For the add method, I'm trying to add a binary number inputted by the user to whatever the user made for the constructor. Thanks so much for any help!

```
public class BinaryNumber implements BinaryNumberInterface
{
    public int x;
    public int input;
    boolean[] oneZero = new boolean[9];
    public BinaryNumber(int input)
    {
        if (input < -256 
        || input > 255)
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException ("Number must be between -256 and 255");
        }

        boolean negative = false;
        int temp = input;
        if (input < 0)
        {
            negative = true;
        }

        for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i --)
        {
            if (temp >= Math.pow (2, i ))
            {
                oneZero [i] = true;
                temp -= Math.pow(2, i);
            }
        }

        if (negative == true)
        {
            this.negate();
        } 
    }

    public BinaryNumber(String num)
    {
        int integer = 0;

        for (int i = num.length() - 1; i >= 0; i --)
        {                     
            String substring = num.substring (i, i + 1);

            if (substring.equals("1")
            && num.length() - i != 9)
            {
                integer += Math.pow (2, num.length() - i - 1 );
            }

        }

        if (num.length() == 9)
        {
            String substring1 = num.substring (8);

            if (substring1.equals("1"))
            {
                integer = integer * -1;
            }
        }       

        BinaryNumber num2 = new BinaryNumber(integer);
    }

    public BinaryNumber add(BinaryNumber input)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for call a constructor of a class you can do this:

```
this(parameter1, parameter2, ...);
```

but is advisable do not use constructors as methods. you should use constructors for initialize attributes with values and methods for manipulate that attributes.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite the way constructors work in java. Your constructor that works with an `int` is written correctly, but your `String` constructor will not function. You are constructing a BinaryNumber instance and never setting its bit array (`oneZero`) and then creating a new BinaryNumber instance at the end of the constructor that just disappears. What you are trying to do is called constructor overloading. In order to call the int constructor, you have to call `this(int)` on the first line of your String constructor. I would suggest reading a bit more about how constructors work: https://www.javatpoint.com/constructor

To make your add(Binary Number) method work, you use the bit arrays of both binary numbers you are adding. For example, if you do this

```
BinaryNumber a = new BinaryNumber(10);
BinaryNumber b = new BinaryNumber(18);
BinaryNumber sum = a.add(b);
```

in the add method of a:

```
public BinaryNumber add(BinaryNumber input){
    /*
    this is a reference to a's array of bits
    oneZero
    //this is a reference to b's array of bits
    input.oneZero
    */
    BinaryNumber result = new BinaryNumber(0);
    //add logic to add the numbers here and set result to the sum of a + b
    return result;
}
```

EDIT:
It just occurred to me that the easiest way for you to implement your string constructor would be to use a factory method, since you are not doing simple parameter loading it would probably work better. Here is how you do it

```
public static BinaryNumber fromString(String input){
    int integer = 0;

        for (int i = num.length() - 1; i >= 0; i --)
        {                     
            String substring = num.substring (i, i + 1);

            if (substring.equals("1")
            && num.length() - i != 9)
            {
                integer += Math.pow (2, num.length() - i - 1 );
            }

        }

        if (num.length() == 9)
        {
            String substring1 = num.substring (8);

            if (substring1.equals("1"))
            {
                integer = integer * -1;
            }
        }
    return new BinaryNumber(integer);
}
```

and you call it with `BinaryString a = BinaryString.fromString("10100");`

Answer (score 0):

Calling a constructor using `new MyClass(...)` from within another constructor will not magically replace `this` with the new instance so created.

I think want you want is this:

```
public BinaryNumber(String num) {
    int integer = 0;

    // calculate what integer is

    this(integer);
}
```

but in java, nested constructor calls must be the *first* statement in the outer constructor.

The workaround is this:

```
public BinaryNumber(String num) {
    this(stringToInteger(num));
}

private static int stringToInteger(String num) {
    int integer = 0;

    // calculate what integer is

    return integer;
}
```